# SQL Inner query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of users. Each user has a certain type, but the type of the user can change, and I needed to record the past types of each student.

So I have

```
user_table
----------------
user_id     user_first_name ...


type_table
---------------
type_id   type_desc     


type_change_table
----------------
change_id    user_id   type_id      date_of_change   date_of_input
```

Hopefully the above 3 table are understandable. So if I want to change a user type I input the type change into type_change_table, time-stamping the date of input (which may be different to the actual date the user changes his/her type- date_of_change). Then I have a complete log of each user's type history, and when each change was input into the database.

My problem is trying to perform a certain SQL query.
In English the query is:

> Get all the users who changed their type with date_of_input TODAY and whose type before the change was TYPE.

Where TYPE and TODAY are variables.
e.g. I want to know who input a type change today and from what type was the change made.

I am really not sure how to handle this kind of query in SQL, which I think requires at least one inner query, to select the second to last type of a user in ASC order).

How should I go about making this query?

Comment: Could you please seed some sample data, provide expected output?

Comment: must it be "the second to last type of a user in ASC order"?

Comment: Is date of change next to date of input, or is it before? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing the `type_change_table` informs the new `type_id` and not the old one. If so, you will need to get the maximum date of change before the desired date_of_change (found by the `date_of_input`). I selected a bunch of fields to get maximum information about the change, but you can choose what you will really need.

The select would be:

```
SELECT 
   A.change_id, 
   A.date_of_change, 
   A.date_of_input ,
   A.USER_ID, 
   D.user_first_name, 
   B.type_id id_old_type, 
   E.type_desc id_old_type_desc, 
   A.type_id id_new_Type, 
   F.type_desc id_new_type_desc
FROM (
    -- This subquery gets the last change type --> maximum date before actual change
    SELECT actual_type.type_id, actual_type.user_id, actual_type.change_id, actual_type.date_of_change, actual_type.date_of_input, max(old_type.date_of_change) last_change_before_today
    FROM type_change_table actual_type 
    INNER JOIN type_change_table old_type
      ON actual_type.user_id = old_type.user_id
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(actual_type.date_of_input, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-07-18'
       AND old_type.date_of_change < actual_type.date_of_change
    GROUP BY actual_type.user_id, actual_type.change_id
) A
-- B gets the last user type
INNER JOIN type_change_table B
   ON A.user_id = B.user_id
   AND A.last_change_before_today = B.date_of_change
-- D gets the user data 
INNER JOIN user_table D
   ON A.user_id = D.user_id
-- E gets the description of old_type
INNER JOIN type_table E
  ON B.type_id = E.type_id
-- F gets the descrioption of new type
INNER JOIN type_Table F
  ON A.type_id = F.Type_id
WHERE E.type_desc = 'Type 1'
```

**You can define the parameters replace the values in the query**

Please look the SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7d0d/1)

Answer (score 0):

This does find the "second to last" record by using ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 inside the exists subquery. I presume you mean "second to last" using DESC order though.

Not sure which of the date fields you wish to use, I chose date_of_change, change as needed.

```
   /*Get all the users who changed their type with date_of_input TODAY 
    and whose type before the change was TYPE.*/


SET @today := '2014-07-26 00:00:00';
SET @type  := 4;

SELECT
      tct.user_id
    , ut.user_first_name
    , tct.type_id
    , tt.type_desc
FROM type_change_table tct
      INNER JOIN user_table ut
                  ON tct.user_id = ut.user_id
      INNER JOIN type_table tt
                  ON tct.type_id = tt.type_id
WHERE tct.date_of_change = @today
      AND EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  NULL
            FROM type_change_table prev
            WHERE tct.user_id = prev.user_id
                  AND date_of_change < @today
                  AND prev.type_id = @type
        ORDER BY date_of_change DESC
        LIMIT 1
      );
```

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64a64/5)

Answer (score -2):

use this

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE user_id IN(
    SELECT  user_id 
    FROM type_change_table tct INNER JOIN
        type_table tt ON tct.type_ID = tt.type_id
    WHERE 
        date_of_change = 'PUT DATE HERE' AND 
        type_desc = 'PUT TYPE HERE'
)
```

Comment: not by me, but your query does not meet the requirement (you have just placed 2 conditions into a simple where clause) re-read the question. One condition is for a date = today, the other condition is for a certain type and that change is < today